# Wiring 5V ultrasonic sensor to Arduino Due

Tags: sensors, shields, arduino-due, voltage-level

Is it possible to use the [2760342 ultrasonic range sensor](http://www.radioshack.com/radioshack-ultrasonic-range-sensor/2760342.html) with an Arduino Due? The docs say it takes a 5V input, but doesn't specify the output, but I'm assuming it also outputs a 5V signal. Does this make it incompatible with the Due?

I've tested it with an Uno, it it works flawlessly. I've been researching using a Due and some other ARM based single-board computers, but they all seem to use 3.3V, while almost all Arduino shields and sensors use 5V. I'm hesitant to "upgrade" to these boards if I have to purchase an entire new set of shields and sensors. And I have no interest in hacking in some clunky custom voltage level shifter. Why isn't everything standardized on 5V?

Answer (score 1):

Is this too clunky?

https://www.adafruit.com/products/735

Breadboard Friendly 8-bit Logic Level Shifter, $1.50.

Comment: Yes. I have no interest in buying an $80 SBC and then spending weeks debugging my own hacky level shifter circuit. That's like buying a new car for $30k and then having to make your own tires...

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "Why isn't everything standardized on 5v?", see this good SO answer:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/135841/voltage-standards-like-3-3v-5v-etc

Bottom line is that the voltage drops as the electronics' technology advances (12v to 5v to 3.3v).

Concretely to your problem, I honestly do not think that a level shifter is somewhat "clunky" solution to your problem, as suggested by mikeY (and as rejected by you). This is the way things are done in the electronics world - when a hardware mismatch arises, there is a hardware adapter to rescue.